# Play Framework: Solution for storing a Map, key - value using JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am struggling for almost a week of how to store a HashMap using JPA in Play. All the other attributes are stored, only the HashMap has zero elements (is empty).

```
public class ImageModel extends Model {

 @Id
 private String id;
 private String url;

 @ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
 @MapKeyClass(java.lang.String.class)
 private Map<String,String> tags = new HashMap<>();

 // the method for adding keys and values to the HashMap
 public void add(String key, String value){
    tags.put(key,value);
    this.save();
}

}
```

I also tried to annotate with:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

So, my only guess for now is that I have not configured well Play. (I must say that I am using Play2 and haven't configured anything, except deleting "#" (comment mark) in front of database settings).

On Play documentation says: "**There is no built-in JPA implementation in Play 2.0**". Could be that the case?

**Update**: I have made some research and said that could be because I'm using the default database from Play - H2. I tried with MySQL - [video how to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwDlnTg_H-o) , but again it saves only the id and url. I looked in MySQL database and table with the name of the class had only 2 attribute (id and url), no trace of my HashMap.

**Update2**: Added a print screen - [with database query.](http://prntscr.com/17b2t9)

**Update3**: The sample "computer-database-jpa" from Play is working fine, so the JPA should be fine, but that sample didn't used a Map (HashMap). I even changed hibernate with EclipseLink, but still not working. :( (although, all the basic types attributes are in database)

Comment: you see the sample project provided(computer-database-jpa) in the play framework folder to verify the configuration.

Comment: I tested computer-database-jpa from java folder and works fine.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Play Framework. The other attributes are saved, so the persistence is working. You should modify the title and the tags of your question, you'd have more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I implemented a HashMap using your models.

```
@Entity
public class ImageModel extends Model {
    //All your fields, etc.

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "imagesWithTag")
    @MapKey(name = "name")
    public Map<String,Tag> tags = new HashMap<String,Tag>();
}

@Entity
public class Tag extends Model {
    // All your fields, etc.

    public String name;
    public String value;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<ImageModel> imagesWithTag = new ArrayList<ImageModel>();
}
```

I decided to go with Eric's suggestion of creating an entire model for Tag, as to make queries easily, but there are times where being able to use the functionalities of a Map will help a lot.  This should work for EnumMaps too.

```
public void addTag(String tagName, String value) {
    Tag tag = Tag.finderTag.where().eq("name", tagName).eq("value", value).findUnique();
    if(tag == null) {
        tag = Tag.newTag(tagName, value);
    }
    this.tags.put(tag.name, tag);
    this.saveManyToManyAssociations("tags");
}

public static List<ImageModel> getImagesWithTag(String tagName, String tagValue) {

    Tag tag = finderTag.where().eq("name", tagName).eq("value", tagValue).findUnique();

    List<ImageModel> images = new ArrayList<ImageModel>();
    for(ImageModel model : tag.imagesWithTag) {
        images.add(model);
    }
    return images;
}
```

I have seen barely anything about using Maps in Play Framework models, so I decided to create a small sample project (Play 2.1.1) to toy around with and further demonstrate map use.

https://github.com/Raymond26/play-framework-demos/tree/master/PlayMap

Comment: Thank you for your response and for your whole example from github. I am sincerely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question here is:
Why store these tags in a Map? I guess it will be some kind of `key->value` pair like `"author"->"John Smith"`, `"theme"->"Animals"`, etc. right?

IMHO, you should have a type `Tag`:

```
@Entity
class Tag {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    // getters, setters, hashCode, equals, etc.
    // ...
}
```

and have a relationship in `ImageModel`:

```
public class ImageModel extends Model {
    // ...
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Tag> tags;
    // ...
}
```

Here you have a strong typed collection which make really explicit what the relation is.

This way, you could add some interesting stuff on `Tag` like a unique constraint, some validation (JSR303), additionnal fields, Javadoc, unit tests, etc.

Also, this allow you to do some useful queries easily, such as:

- search images by tag
- list existing tags
- list tags with name "author"
- ...